# Having issues extracing using Regex

Tags: regex

I am trying to do an simple text extraction, but having issues.

Here is what I'm wanting to extract from:

### Downtown, Lincoln, Nebraska - Map

Here is my regex:

```
/*[,](.*)[-]

$1
```

My result =

```
, San Francisco,
```

I want to grab just the `city` (Lincoln) and just the `state` (State).

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What language? You don't need regex here. PHP: `list($area, $city, $state) = explode(', ', $your_string);`

Comment: It's not for PHP, I am using scrape tool and trying to extract from within the DIVs so I have to create the regex for specific parts.

Comment: Hey Guys, I just found this within the code that might make it more uniformed 

<DD class=location uid="7">Downtown, Lincoln, Nebraska - <A title="Google Map" href="http://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&amp;q=Downtown, Lincoln, Nebraska" target=_blank uid="8" peppyCount="12">Map</A>

so I would want to get the "Lincoln" part and "Nebraska" part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Javascript you can do using lookahead:

```
Downtown, San Francisco, California - Map'.match(/ *([^,]+?),(?=[^,]*$) *([^ -]+)/)
//=> [" San Francisco, California", "San Francisco", "California"]
```

Whatever tool/language you're using you can translate this regex.

Comment: Hey @anubhava I couldn't get this to work? I can't seperate the city and state.

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: Using a content transformation script within a scraper program. When I run your string as is, I just duplicated the string I am extracting.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks @anubhava seeing it on regex101 worked great.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Downtown is City and the California is Sate name:

```
^(\S+),[^,]*,\s*([^-]*)
```

Look for `$1` and `$2`

Comment: Hey @Sabuj thanks for replying, this didn't work for me. After looking at the string more, I have having better luck extracting directly from the html: 

<DD class=location uid="7">Downtown, Lincoln, Nebraska - <A title="Google Map" href="http://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&amp;q=Downtown, Lincoln, Nebraska" target=_blank uid="8" peppyCount="12">Map</A>

I am trying to extract from this part:
;q=Downtown, Lincoln, Nebraska"

I need to get "Lincoln" and then "Nebraska" separately. 

Each sample I've tried below gives me an error back.